# std::ranges::view as mutable class member

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges

I have a huge data structure and it's content is updated regularly.
I need to apply a filter to it each time I get a change request.
So to avoid duplicating/copying it, I use an std::view + std::views::filter. (as lightweight container)

Having this class

```cpp
class MyClass
{
   std::map<std::string, std::set<std::string>> myData;
   // How to add the view as class member based on myData ?
};
```

How can I create this view inside a class.
What type to specify ?
How to intialize it ?
Is it possible to reassign it ?

Comment: I don't know what this question is asking.

Comment: The question is what's the concrete type to use and how to intialize, reassign the view class member

Comment: Having a view as a class member is pretty suspect, why do you think you need that? What are you trying to accomplish with it?

Comment: It's to avoid creating a filtred copy of myData. As views are lightweight containers

Comment: I... don't follow. You could write a function that returns a filtered view over myData.

Comment: This function will be called many times and do the same job and returning the same result. Why not storing the result as class member ?

Comment: Because the function is cheap, works, and is easy to reason about.

Comment: But this function will loop over all the map. In a hot/critic execution path it will be expensive

Comment: It will not "loop over all the map" - you're just creating a filtered view. That's a lazy operation, it does no work.

Comment:  How is that possible?

Comment: Because that's how views work, that's what they are. I suggest you look into what views are, there are a few good talks on the topic (e.g. by Tristan Brindle).

Comment: @Barry, given those programs, https://godbolt.org/z/dT8eeW6jG and https://godbolt.org/z/345Wx1oeP. Built using gcc 13 and O3 optimization I got a huge difference regarding the execution time. 6 seconds for the version without view and 56 seconds for the program with view. Do I miss something?